Проблема запуска бота с помощью фреймворка aiogram через локальный сервер
Нужно запустить бота через локальный сервер, чтобы обойти ограничение бота на принятие файла в размере от 50 мб.
При запуске кода через локальный сервер происходит ошибка: aiogram.utils.exceptions.Unauthorized: Unauthorized: invalid token specified
Вот код создающий оболочку бота:
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.bot.api import TelegramAPIServer
 
import logging
 
from settings.file_settings import API_KEY_TG
 
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
 
local_server = TelegramAPIServer.from_base('http://localhost:8080/bot')
 
bot = Bot(token=API_KEY_TG, server = local_server)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())

Вот, непосредственно, сам файл старта бота:
from aiogram import executor
from create_bot import dp
from handlers import start_connect
 
async def on_startup(_):
    print("Bot Online!")
    
start_connect.register_handlers_start_connect(dp)
    
def main():
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Сервер запущен (Запускаю следующей команде в папке с exe файлом):
path\telegram-bot-api.exe --api-id=****--api-hash=**** --http-port=8080 --http-stat-port=8090 --dir=C:\TMP\data --temp-dir=C:\TMP\tmp

Однако, при смене сервера на ('http://localhost:8080'), то бот запускается, НО(!), не через локальный сервер.
Как я это понял?
Во-первых, выбивается ошибка при отправке файла свыше 50мб, а именно: aiogram.utils.exceptions.FileIsTooBig: File is too big
Во-вторых, при попытке пропинговать бота в cmd командой
curl http://localhost:8080

приходит такой ответ:
{"ok":false,"error_code":404,"description":"Not Found"}

Однако при пробивке по такому коду, приходит следующее
C:\Windows\system32>curl http://localhost:8080/bot/getMe

{"ok":false,"error_code":401,"description":"Unauthorized: invalid token specified"}

Нуждаюсь в Вашей помощи!
